# What layout would be best to use?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to create a layout which stretches and takes up space depending on the screen size. I want to display the following in a layout.

[image]

What would be the best layout to use? I was thinking maybe, Linear layout from the top and Relative layout for the bottom, to align it to parent bottom. But how would I ensure it stretches to fit the screen?

I can use `layout_weight="1"` for the linearlayout to ensure it takes up the screen space but what about the height?

Comment: you should use relative layout as often as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the Drawing Cavas large = 1/2 the screen and other components smaller, I think you should use `linear layout` as the most outer layout and use `layout_weight` to make the canvas bigger than others. When using `layout_weight`, you should make the child components' `layout_height="0dp"`.
Here is what i come up with

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:text="Canvas" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" /><!--Hard coded should be avoided. It depends on the screen size.-->
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's almost working except the buttons becomes too small width-wise when I change the display to a bigger screen.

Comment: Use relative bro... Works everytime

Comment: I found a different method... @dimen for three folders assigning different values in different views. Now to figure out the sizes for each.

Answer (score 2):

In a relative layout you can just set use `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"`, `android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"` and so on for aligning to the screen.

You can use `android:layout_width = "match_parent"` to fill the screen horizontally or `android:layout_height = "match_parent"` to fill it vertically. You can also specify a certain amount like `android:layout_width = "100dp"`.

I suggest you use android studio to see a live preview of the layout, helps a lot.